# UITableView populating Core data one-to-many relationship using checkmark - CoreData: error: Serious application error

Tags: uitableview, core-data, relationship

I have an app where I'm trying to select Resources (buildings, IT Systems) that a Programme relies on. The relationship between the Entities is Resource.resourceusedonprog<<--->Programme.usesresource. A slice of the data model is here:
[image: model slice]

I'm trying to use multiple checkmark selection on a UITableViewController of which resources get used by a particular programme. However, when I try to interact with the Resource cells in the table the app crashes with the error

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught
>   during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an
>   observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  The
>   left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or
>   an NSSet. with userInfo (null)

My code is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Resource Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Resource *resource = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", resource.hasmanager.firstname, resource.hasmanager.surname];
    cell.textLabel.text = resource.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = fullname;

    if (resource.resourceusedonprog == selectedProgramme){ cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;}
    else {cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;}
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
     Resource *resource = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        resource.resourceusedonprog = NULL;
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        resource.resourceusedonprog = selectedProgramme;

        }    }
```

The error seems to be triggered by the resource.resourceusedonprog = selectedProgramme; and resource.resourceusedonprog = NULL; events. if I comment them out I can check and uncheck the cells (but clearly, not change the state of resource.resourceusedonprog, i.e. what I'm trying to achieve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, which is based on two issues. Firstly, the relationship key is an NSSet, not an object, for a many-to-many relationship. Secondly, the NSManagedObject Subclass for each entity automatically generates add and remove methods for each relationship. In the case of this one I've implemented

`[resource removeResourceusedonprogObject:selectedProgramme];` and

```
[resource addResourceusedonprogObject:selectedProgramme];
```

The overall code is here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Resource Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    Resource *resource = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *fullname = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", resource.hasmanager.firstname, resource.hasmanager.surname];
    cell.textLabel.text = resource.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = fullname;

    if ([resource.resourceusedonprog containsObject:selectedProgramme]){ cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;}
    else {cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;}
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
     Resource *resource = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path];
     NSLog(@"selectedResource is: %@", resource.name);
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [resource removeResourceusedonprogObject:selectedProgramme];
        } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            [resource addResourceusedonprogObject:selectedProgramme];


        }    }
```